# Snakemake: Constrain output to list of files

Tags: python, snakemake

I do have a dictionary of {"file" -> "url"} mappings and would like to download these using Snakemake.
The corresponding download rule looks like this:

```py
 rule download_file:
     output:
         file="{file}"
     params:
         url=lambda wildcards: files_to_url_dict[wildcards.file],
     shell: """wget "{params.url}" -o "{output.file}""""
```

However, the output rule does match any possible file now.
In other words, I cannot use any other rules any more.

How do I constrain the output to the file names in `files_to_url_dict.keys()`?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to find a pattern in the filenames of the keys in your dictionary, and to employ this information:

```py
rule download_file:
    output:
        file="prefix{wildcard1}affix{wildcard2}suffix"
    params:
        url=lambda wildcards: files_to_url_dict[f"prefix{wildcards.wildcard1}affix{wildcards.wildcard2}suffix"],
    shell: """wget "{params.url}" -o "{output.file}" """
```

This is a recommended way, as providing magic dictionaries is not an idiomatic solution for Snakemake: its power is to retrieve the information from the directory structure based on the known patterns.

If you don't know these prefix/affix/suffix, but know some restrictions that may distinguish the files to download from other files, you may use `wildcard_constraints`:

```py
rule download_file:
    output:
        file="{file}"
    wildcard_constraints:
        file=<provide your regex here>
    params:
        url=lambda wildcards: files_to_url_dict[wildcards.file],
    shell: """wget "{params.url}" -o "{output.file}" """
```

See more about wildcard constraints [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards).

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed description of constraints.
My issue is that I do not know the folder structure that should be downloaded beforehand.
However, I want to create an index for every file which ends with `.vcf.gz`.
Does `wildcard_constraints` also take a list of files?

Comment: wildcard_constraints is a regular expression. You could try to create it from the list of files, but note that the result shall be ready prior to Snakemake starts creating a DAG.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is really that your `download_file` rule can match any output. To fix this, you need to make this rule's output less general. One strategy is to put the output of `download_file` in its own directory:

```
rule download_file:
  ...
  output:
    file="download_file/{file}"
  ...
```

Other rules can then use the downloaded file as input by referring to the input file string:

```
rule gzip:
  input:
    file="download_file/{file}"
  output:
    gzipped="gzipped/{file}"
  shell:
    "gzip -c {input.file} > {output.gzipped}"
```

Or the output of `download_file` directly:

```
rule gzip:
  input:
    file=rules.download_file.output.file
  ...
```

Here's a short working example:

```
import shlex

files_to_url_dict = {
  "sample1": "https://storage.googleapis.com/gatk-test-data/wgs_ubam/NA12878_20k/NA12878_A.bam",
  "sample2": "https://storage.googleapis.com/gatk-test-data/wgs_ubam/NA12878_20k/NA12878_B.bam",
}

rule collect_reads:
  input:
    sam = ["uncompressed/{file}.sam".format(file=file) for file in files_to_url_dict.keys()]
  output:
    concat_reads = "collected/all_reads.txt"
  params:
    shlex_input = lambda wldc, input: ' '.join(map(shlex.quote, input.sam)) # Handle samples/files with spaces
  shell:
    """
    cat {params.shlex_input} > '{output.concat_reads}'
    """

rule download_file:
  output:
    file = "download_file/{file}"
  params:
    url = lambda wildcards: files_to_url_dict[wildcards.file],
  shell:
    """
    wget '{params.url}' -o '{output.file}'
    """

rule bam_to_sam:
  input:
    file = rules.download_file.output.file,
  output:
    sam = temp("uncompressed/{file}.sam")
  shell:
    """
    samtools view '{input.file}' > '{output.sam}'
    """
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, the output rule does match any possible file now. In other words, I cannot use any other rules any more.

> How do I constrain the output to the file names in files_to_url_dict.keys()?

I don't understand what you mean by that. What is it in the example below that doesn't work for you?

```
files2url = {'sample1':'http://foo.txt', 
             'sample2':'http://bar.txt'}

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{sample}.txt', sample= files2url.keys()),

rule download_file:
    output:
        sample= '{sample}.tmp',
    params:
        url= lambda wc: files2url[wc.sample],
    shell:
        r"""
        wget "{params.url}" -o "{output.sample}"
        """

rule copy_file:
    input:
        '{sample}.tmp',
    output:
        '{sample}.txt',
    shell:
        r"""
        cp {input} {output}
        """
```